# Grails Resources Plugin encoding issue with code = html

Tags: grails, character-encoding

According to Marc Palmer

[Preventing XSS attacks](http://grailsrocks.com/blog/2013/4/19/can-i-pwn-your-grails-application)

> In a nutshell, to protect your app from code injection XSS exploits
>   you must:
>
> Set the default grails.views.default.codec in config to "HTML"

OK.
So if I have this below in my Config.groovy

```
grails.views.default.codec = "none"
```

And in my Controller, I add:

```
def afterInterceptor = { model ->   
    model.headerJs = "alert('bingo for '+[$params.unitId]);"
}
```

And in my GSP:

```
<r:script disposition="head">${headerJs}</r:script>
```

It works.  I see the expected javascript alert when I do View Source and I get my alert when the page serves.

But, if in Config.groovy I apply the recommended change:

```
grails.views.default.codec = "html"
```

My GSP renders

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert(&#39;halooba for &#39;+[1]);</script>
```

which I can see is very secure.

My goal with this app is to have custom JS snippets, various properties and other values stored for the customer in the Domain. These values would be entered by our Admins (not the customer).  Based on who invokes the page with an HTTP request, such as www.mydomain.com/ThisApp/?customerId=13423  (but an encoded customerId) I'd make calls to Services from my Controller to fetch the associated settings for the customer from the Domain and inject them into the GSP.

I know that I can put JS and CSS into files and then use the Resources Plugin to bring them in properly, but I'm also looking at this method for specific customizations.

So, to follow this security method, I either need to be able to unencode this, or I need to determine another method for including javascript into the GSP that does not encode it.

Any suggestions?

THANKS!

Comment: The question needs to be changed from code = html to codec = html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can suggest Grails not to escape by using [raw()](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.1/guide/security.html#xssPrevention) available in GSP as:

```
<r:script disposition="head">${raw(headerJs)}</r:script>
```

Comment: Good. But my project is running 2.2.4. I'm trying to upgrade it to 2.3.4 but running into failur to resolve dependency errors with org.grails.plugins: tomecat: 2.3.4 and org.grails.plugins:hibernate:2.3.4. Is there a method like raw() prior to 2.3?

Comment: This does not work: `<r:script disposition="head">${headerJs.decodeHTML()}</r:script>`

Comment: This solution might work, if I ever get my app to work with Grails 2.3.4+.  But right now, I'm on 2.2.4.  Tried the upgrade but gave up after an hour of dependency issue hell.

Comment: RAW() DOES NOT WORK IN <HEAD> @dmahapatro So, raw() does work in a regular html tag in the <body>.  But in the <head> section, it only renders escaped.

Comment: WORKAROUND TO GET RAW() WORKING IN <HEAD>  This will render the value without encoding it: `<sometag>${raw(new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.FastStringWriter().append(headerJs).buffer)}</sometag>` where headerJs is what you want to render.

Answer (score 0):

For Grails 2.2.x and below, you can put the recommended encoding in your Config.groovy:

```
grails.views.default.codec = "html"
```

and use a Taglib to bring in values that are SAFE and should not be HTML encoded:

```
<r:script><com_myapp:getJSDeferred  unitId="${params.unitId}" /></r:script>
```

and it will be rendered raw.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Above solution will not allow for JSON output to assign to javascript variable.
My workaround, say you have model.data defined as hashmap:

```
var someVar= ${raw(data as JSON).toString())};
```